# Disable node drag in force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Implemented force layout, here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8tcd9/6/). However I want to disable the drag behaviour for the nodes, drag event will move the nodes across and set the nodes center to cursor position until mouseup event. Is there a way we can disable this?  I tried removing the callback from the nodes as follows:

```
node.append("svg:circle").attr("r",5).style("fill", "#FE9A2E").on("mousedown.drag", null)
```

This didn't work. not sure if it will remove the callback from the node. also tried fixing the node position on drag event by setting fixed property of the node to true. But that fixes the node after it has been dragged. how can I stop the nodes from dragging?

Comment: Just a clarification:  Do you want to completely remove the drag behaviour from the code (i.e., which lines to take out without messing everything up), or do you want to be able to turn it on and off?

Comment: @AmeliaBR I want to completely remove the drag behaviour from the code. Is there any easy way of doing it?

Comment: Strangely, the drag behaviour in the `sticky force layout` got disabled only when I commented out this part `.call(zoom).on("dblclick.zoom", null);`. Rather perplexing that zoom is related to drag.

Answer (score 2):

The default drag behaviour is added to the nodes in the last part of this statement:

```
var node = vis.selectAll("g.node").data(nodeSet).enter()
    .append("svg:g").attr("class", "node").call(force.drag);
```

Just remove the `.call(force.drag)` and you can no longer move around individual nodes.  If you also want to get rid of the behaviour where you can move around the entire graph, it is part of the "zoom" behaviour added in the last line of this statement:

```
var vis = d3.select(".journalGraph").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", w).attr("height", h)
    .attr("pointer-events", "all").append('svg:g')
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw)).append('svg:g');
```

Removing the call statement would get rid of both the pan and zoom functionality.  See https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior for more on zooming.

Comment: Thanks, works fine if i remove the lines you mentioned from the code. I earlier tried removing the call(force.drag) statement but as the zoom and pan was there it was still dragging it. How is that with zoom and pan i am not able to disable drag? I need zoom behavior for the layout.

Comment: I think the idea for the pan behaviour is so that when you are zoomed in you can still move around to see the entire image.  You probably don't want to disable that, but you can turn off panning when not zoomed in by adding the statement `if (d3.event.scale <= 1) return;` as the first line of your `redraw()` method.  See the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8tcd9/7/); I also added a `scaleExtent([1,10])` to the zoom behaviour to make it zoom-in only.  If you wanted to turn off panning completely, even when zoomed in, just remove the `translate(...)` part of that method's return statement.

Comment: Wait, correction -- that approach causes problems if you pan when zoomed in, then zoom out again (the image isn't centred and you can't fix it!).  Make it `if (d3.event.scale <= 1) vis.transition().duration(500)
        .attr("transform", "none");` to get a smooth reset when zooming back out: http://jsfiddle.net/8tcd9/8/